# Play an Audio file in boot-up screen?

Tags: boot, sound, customization

So I'm not supper new to Linux and Ubuntu, but I'm not a pro either. I downloaded Xubuntu and started customizing a bit (Themes, backgrounds, ect).

One thing that I wanted to do was add a boot-up sound when the first splash screen pops up, before the login screen currently no sounds play not even Ubuntu's "system-ready.ogg", but the rest of the system sounds work once signed in (soundtheme set to Ubuntu and files are present). I found out very easily how to add a custom one on login from: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1869787 using "Sox" (by adding a program to the auto start with "play /audio/directory") so I tried to do the same in the local.rc I started by creating a script that plays the audio file /usr/src/bootsound.sh in the script file I have the following...

```
#!/...
play /home/toshibaxu/Music/boot.ogg
```

I can run the script and it plays the audio file in the terminal fine weather I double click or use the terminal command so that seems fine. So then I went to add it to the local.rc which currently has the following in it...

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

sh '/usr/src/bootsound.sh
exit 0
```

But the audio file doesn't play on boot, I have tried searching around and I can't seem to find anything about playing audio on boot screen. I admit I could be going about this all wrong, I don't know. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the first one. #!/...
play /home/toshibaxu/Music/boot.ogg

Comment: Maybe at that moment the sound system and/or device are not already defined. Maybe setting `AUDIODRIVER`and `AUDIODEV`could help (see `man play`)

Comment: Suggestion: Try adding few seconds of delay before playing the audio i.e. `sleep 5`. Adjust this value according to your boot time, which is how long the system takes to reach the login screen.